# Clarification about keyring naming in Linux key retention subystem

Tags: linux, kernel

I am playing around with the Linux's *Key Retention System* (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/security/keys/core.html) and I need a clarification about the keys naming conventions when using `keyctl` command from user-space...

For showing the content of a keyring named `.fs-verity` (yes, I am also playing around with https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/filesystems/fsverity.html...) I ended up with a command (found somewhere on the web) like:

```
keyctl show %:.fs-verity
```

But I am not really aware of what it means...

I mean: the keyring is named `.fs-verity`, but if I do not prefix its name with `%:` then `keyctl` complains that `.fs-verity` is an unparsable key... so what `%:` stands for? What the rationale behind that? Can you point me out a good resource on web to dig into details? I cannot find anything...